# How can I use “Ctrl + Shift + V” to paste plain, non-formatted text, into a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

In Chrome, I can paste text without any formatting using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. How can I do something like this in in Microsoft Word?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shortcut in Word or Excel for Special Paste?](https://superuser.com/questions/407113/shortcut-in-word-or-excel-for-special-paste) - this also includes an answer that doesn't require any macros (just 4 keys).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are the steps:

- From the View tab, click on Macros -> View Macros
- In the Macros dialog, enter `PasteSpecial` in the macro name field and click Create.
- Replace the contents of the code editor with the following code:

```
Sub PasteSpecial()
On Error GoTo errHandler

        Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
        Exit Sub
    
errHandler:
        Selection.Paste
End Sub
```

- Save and close the code editor
- Go to File tab -> Options -> Customize Ribbon, click on the Customize... button after "keyboard shortcuts:"
- Choose `Macro` in the Categories box and choose `PasteSpecial` in the Macros box. In `Press new shortcut key` box, enter <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, then click Assign.
- Click OK to close the Word Options dialog.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Go to File> Options> Customize Ribbon> [Keyboard Shortcuts] Customize... > All Commands > PastTextOnly> Press new shortcut key: > Assign> Close.

It doesn't need any codes or something!

Comment: This is the best option without using macro as this function is available in Word, and we just need to assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Answer (score 6):

### "Paste as plain text" – Universal macro which works with any application

This is [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) macro which will paste clipboard content as non-formatted text in any application which by default works with formatted text (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, Outlook, Write, you name it.)

Keyboard shortcut: **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>**

```
^#v::   ;work with clipboard: paste clipboard content as plain text
    ClipboardOld := ClipboardAll  ;save original clipboard contents
    Clipboard = %Clipboard%  ;store plain text from clipboard to clipboard
    Send ^v  ;send the Ctrl+V command
    Sleep, 250  ;give some time to finish paste (before restoring clipboard)
    Clipboard := ClipboardOld  ;restore the original clipboard contents
    ClipboardOld =  ;clear temporary variable (potentially contains large data)
    Return
```

Answer (score 2):

After all these years, Microsoft is finally adding the ability to Shift-Control-V paste as value natively.  It's in the [Beta versions of Word as of March 2023](https://www.theverge.com/2023/3/9/23632415/microsoft-word-control-shift-v-paste-shortcut-plaintext).