# Shortcut key to remove formatting after pasting?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, copy-paste, clipboard

I'm copying and pasting a lot of citations, and the formatting comes out of my browser, into my document.  I use the "dark reader" extension in Chrome so all of my text is wrongly formatted when it is pasted into my word document.

How do I remove formatting by pressing a hotkey?

This seems to be working in 2013 - 2020 (please let me know if you've tested other versions).

Comment: Thank you very much for the interesting content, but the questions are a little dissimilar. The title of that post is jargony and misleading rather than using laymen's language, and the responses are for a different version of word (a much more technical solution is requierd).  An answer was never accepted, and the goal is to "remove formatting" (not seen on that page).

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/648707/911683) answer on the question that @harrymc mentioned does exactly what you're looking for. It's just not a single hotkey. You haven't told us which version of Word you're using, so you're going to get generic answers, but I tested this in Word 2016 and it works there too.

Comment: Thanks, Worthwelle.  The reason I didn't want to delete this posted (though I don't mind having it closed in the slightest) is because I polled people and nobody knew what special paste meant.  XD

Comment: That's perfectly valid and is the whole reason we have duplicates. This way there are multiple ways to find the information. :)

Comment: @Worthwelle Really appreciate the info.  Helps me to keep it from getting to my head.  I had thought the info would be hidden from the public eye prior to this comment line.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>m</kbd>--merge formatting--, or <kbd>t</kbd>--text only.